# Is it possible to copy the default frambuffer to a framebuffer object without showing anything on the screen?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, glew, fbo

If so, I can save the content of the FBO as an image file.

Other question:
This image will have a resolution related with the screen?
Or, it will have the same resolution as the input image that was texturized on the default framebuffer?

Was my question clear?

Answer (score 1):

Copying between framebuffers: `glBlitFramebuffer`

see here https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glBlitFramebuffer.xml

`This image will have a resolution related with the screen?`

The resolution can be set in the `glBlitFramebuffer` function. The default framebuffer has the size of your opengl window (can be different than the screen).

`Is it possible to copy the default frambuffer to a framebuffer object without showing anything on the screen?`

The image is usually first rendered offscreen and displayed when calling `swapBuffers` (double buffering). So without calling `swapBuffers` nothing is shown on the screen.

Keep in mind though, that you can render directly into framebuffers objects and you don't have to first render it into the default framebuffer and then copy it over. To do that just call `glBindFramebuffer` before your actual draw calls.

Comment: So, if I use directly the FBO, will the FBO also have the size of the opengl window (that I am hiding)?

I already have a code that does a surface model texturization (triangles in a 3D coordinate system being "colorized" using two different textures - input images) and shows the result on the screen.

But, I tried to use an approach to render it directly to a FBO but I did not get a result. I did not understand properly how to deal with FBO (one dimension) and two textures (2 different dimensions).

Comment: The size of a FBO is the same as the textures attached to it. You should probably read through a FBO tutorial for example here: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/

Comment: I will have a look at this material, thank you!
By the way, how does it work if my textures ( I am using 2) do not have the same size? Can I define the size of my FBO? Sorry if my question does not make too much sense!

Comment: From opengl.org: `Notice that there is no restriction based on size. The effective size of the FBO is the intersection of all of the sizes of the bound images (ie: the smallest in each dimension). ` So the size of the FBO would be the size of the smaller texture. The additional pixels of the bigger texture are then not written while rendering and stay empty.

Comment: I used directly the FBO and I saved the result as an image file. But, the output has color information only in part of it (the size of my screen resolution). I set the glViewport to be the size of my output. Do you know how can I get the rest of the information that do not appear on the output image?